# Nagios notifications by host AND service

Tags: nagios

I'd like to configure Nagios to send an alert to UserA when either HostA or any service on HostA has a problem. The first part - when HostA has a problem - is straightforward, but I can't see how to send an alert to a given user when any service on a given host (or group of hosts) has a problem. To be clear:

If any service on HostA has a problem, notify UserA
If any service on HostB has a problem, notify UserB

Any pointers or ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nagios service notifications for specific hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412129/nagios-service-notifications-for-specific-hosts)

Comment: There is a dupe of this question which has a much better answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412129/nagios-service-notifications-for-specific-hosts?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

In the service definition, you'll need to set the contact_groups (and define the groups elsewhere). Here's an example:

```
define service{
    name                            A-service ; The 'name' of this service template
    active_checks_enabled           1       ; Active service checks are enabled
    passive_checks_enabled          1       ; Passive service checks are enabled/accepted
    parallelize_check               1       ; Active service checks should be parallelized
    obsess_over_service             1       ; We should obsess over this service (if necessary)
    check_freshness                 0       ; Default is to NOT check service 'freshness'
    notifications_enabled           1       ; Service notifications are enabled
    event_handler_enabled           1       ; Service event handler is enabled
    flap_detection_enabled          1       ; Flap detection is enabled
    failure_prediction_enabled      1       ; Failure prediction is enabled
    process_perf_data               1       ; Process performance data
    retain_status_information       1       ; Retain status information across program restarts
    retain_nonstatus_information    1       ; Retain non-status information across program restarts
    notification_interval           0       ; Only send notifications on status$
    is_volatile                     0
    check_period                    24x7
    normal_check_interval           5
    retry_check_interval            1
    max_check_attempts              4
    notification_period             24x7
    notification_options            w,u,c,r
    contact_groups                  A_only  ; >>>Here's the magic you need<<<
    register                        0       ; DONT REGISTER THIS DEFINITION - ITS NOT A REAL SE$
}
# for contact config file
define contactgroup{
    contactgroup_name       A_only
    alias                   APeople
    members                 APerson1, APerson2
}
```

For the B group, change the A_only to B_only and make a new contact group.

Comment: This isn't going to work. It would mean that all the same services need to be defined twice, once for A hosts and once for B hosts.